Looking for an excel formula to check whether a person in an NFL Pick em league is still in the running to win based off remaining games
I have made an excel doc that is keeping track of our NFL Pick em league. I'm looking for a formula to track whether somebody is still in the running to win based off number of correct picks. However, the issue I'm running into is I can't figure out how to compare people's picks if they are still in contention to win.
For example (see attached image):
Player 2 has 9 total picks correct so far and Player 4 & 10 have 7 total picks correct so far with 2 games remaining to be played. Currently it shows that both players (4 & 10) are "still in" when in fact it is impossible for them to win because player 2 and 10 have the same picks remaining so player 10 cannot catch up. Player 2 and 4 have 1 of the 2 picks the same that are remaining but player 4 cannot win either. Both player 4 & 10 should show "out" at this point in the remaining games. Looking for a formula to help correct this issue.
Currently my formula works if a player is behind the same number of games that are remaining, if a player is behind more than games remaining, or if every person in the league has the same picks that are remaining.
Edit
Here is the link to the Excel Doc
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aVwjgrq3BeG1P5G_kWkDkZMn0H7ljvJz/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=106779378627592827864&rtpof=true&sd=true
Edit: Updated screenshot to show formula for in/out column

AM5=IF($AJ5+$AO$16<MAX($AJ$5:$AJ$14),"OUT","STILL IN")
$AJ5 is the current number of correct picks for player 1
$AO$16 takes the remaining games and subtracts them from the $AM$16 (games remaining where every player has the same picks)

can you share the excel file? Basically you'll want a formula that calculates/identifies the leader, checks their remaining picks, then anyone "still in" it'll check if the difference in selected their selected picks is less than the leaders selected picks

What's your current formula?

What are the point in case of win? What do you mean by "same pick", why does player 2 have 50 points with 9 correct. What's with Tie breaker? You really need to share more info if you want a solution.

@excellor I will upload the current excel doc so you can look through it.

@P.b Sorry for the confusion. By same pick I mean if Player 2 and Player 4 choose "BUF" for Game 15, that would be considered the same picks. The Points column is how many points that player thinks will be scored in Game 16 (is used for tie breakers in case players end up with the same amount of correct picks (Monday Night Game)). The Tie breaker Difference column will find the difference between the players Points guess and the Monday Night Score.

@Bgordon81 I'm not allowed to download files/open google sheets on my current device; I'll try to take a look at it when I'm back on my personal device. Can you edit in your current formula?

I updated the attached pic to show the column headers and added in the current formula.
